# Would a delayed:job be executed twice in parallel on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

I have a heroku dyno and I've scheduled a few thousands jobs.

I am starting

`heroku run rake jobs:workoff`

Then I am starting it again.

So two parallel jobs:workoffs are working.

I could not find an answer of whether there is a chance of a single job being executed from the first and from the second workoff. Can this happen? Or it will be prevented and I could rely that a single job is invoked by only one of the workoffs?

Comment: Should be fine as long as all dynos are talking to the same database instance for delayed job queue transactions.

Comment: Thank. TYes, the db is the same. Do you know this from experience or is it written somewhere in the description of the project?